# Generated wallet addresses do not seem random in MyEtherWallet

Tags: wallets, addresses, myetherwallet

I have generated a couple (well, dozens) of accounts with [MyEtherWallet](https://www.myetherwallet.com/) (currently v3.5.6), and strangely every single one of them starts with `"0xff..."`.

I remember doing the same experiment in an older version and getting completely (well, seemingly more) random addresses. But now the first two digits are always `F`. I tried changing the password too. Did something change in the algorithm? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like this is an intentional choice by MEW: the relevant code is [here](https://github.com/kvhnuke/etherwallet/blob/mercury/app/scripts/myetherwallet.js#L20).

```
while (true) {
   var privKey = ethUtil.crypto.randomBytes(32)
   if (ethUtil.privateToAddress(privKey)[0] === 0xFF) {
       return new Wallet(privKey)
    }
}
```

It's essentially generating a vanity address: it generates addresses until the first byte is `ff`.

The commit: https://github.com/kvhnuke/etherwallet/commit/119d741ba3d154d46ffeaab886ca324b3b257644